# How to get a user attribute from an AWS Cognito user pool in Swift?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, swift3, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito user pools with [Amazon's Swift sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift).  I'm able to create users with a `given_name` attribute, but it's not obvious how to later retrieve the `given_name`.

The Amazon sample retrieves attributes as a `AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse` and then dumps them to the screen.  However, I can't find documentation for `AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse`.  It appears to be something of an array, but it's not obvious to me how to just pull out a `given_name` from the returned attributes.  One would think that returning attributes as a dictionary would be a good idea, but it doesn't appear that Amazon did things that way.

Any pointers?

**EDIT:** To clarify, what's returned is an array of `AttributeType` objects.  Here's code in the Cognito sample which displays all returned attributes:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
        indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "attribute", for: indexPath)
    let userAttribute = self.response?.userAttributes![indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = userAttribute?.name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = userAttribute?.value
    return cell
}
```

Here's the raw response:

```
Response body:
{"UserAttributes":[{"Name":"sub","Value":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXXX"},{"Name":"email_verified","Value":"true"},
{"Name":"given_name","Value":"Bob"},
{"Name":"email","Value":"bob@example.com"}],"Username":"AAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE"}
```

It's just not obvious to me how to pull out `given_name` without iterating through the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

Not an iOS expert here, but from what I can see in the [SDK implementation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/b7c4d59954e15d9cbd041f8d1e8c6ef7742f68bb/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityUser.m#L127), it looks like they [copy](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/b7c4d59954e15d9cbd041f8d1e8c6ef7742f68bb/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityUser.m#L133) the details from the AWSCognitoIdentityProviderGetUserResponse, which [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderGetUserResponse.html#//api/name/userAttributes) shows it has the user attributes in the form of a map. Did you try to look for an `userAttributes` array in the response?

Also, the raw [GetUser API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html) says that the UserAttributes should be in the response.

Comment: Yes, I do see that the response is an array, specifically an array of `AttributeType` objects.  I don't see an obvious way to pull out a particular attribute.  Instead, it appears I have to look at each element in the array and see if it contains the key I'm looking for.  I'm kind of new to Swift, so maybe I'm missing something though.  I'll edit my original post to include more info.

Comment: Since the schema is pretty fixed (the baseline attributes are common for everyone and the custom ones were created by you), the attributes are in a map. You can just grab whatever you need out since the keys should be constants.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using `getDetails()` to access `userAttributes`

```
    self.user?.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in // handle all auth setup
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.response = task.result // AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse

            if let attributes = task.result?.userAttributes { // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html
                for attribute in attributes {
                    print(attribute.name, attribute.value)
                    if attribute.name == "name" {
                        // ... do something with name
                    }
                }
            }

        })
        return task
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is not calling for me.